# default indentation in sublimetext

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I use Sublime Text and want JavaScript files to use three spaces for indentaiton.

I set this in `Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings`:

```
{
    "tab_size": 3,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

but it has no affect and I need to manually change it for each new file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you have a JavaScript file open do the following:

> Per-syntax Settings
>
> Settings may be specified on a per-syntax basis. You can edit the
>   settings for the current syntax using the Preferences/Settings -
>   More/Syntax Specific - User menu.

This will allow you to set custom preferences for the current syntax. More info on indentation here: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/indentation.html

Comment: You might also want to disable auto-detect tab size from the file content if you are using the standard Javascript tab is 4 spaces policy. The autodetect overrides the current setting too http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/11/sublime-text-2-tips-for-python-and-web-developers/#Configure_sane_tab_and_whitespace_policy_and_other_settings